# How do you remove the PowerShell requirement that scripts and executables be preceded by ".\"?

Tags: powershell

How do you remove the PowerShell requirement that scripts and executables be preceded by ".\"?

The PowerShell warning message that is shown when "a.exe" is entered instead of ".\a.exe":

```
The command a.exe was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell doesn't load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type ".\a.exe".
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It is a security feature so that you do run scripts that you think you are running. That is why unlike cmd, you do not have `.` ( current directory) in PATH and you have to do `.\my.exe` etc.

If you don't want to do this and subvert this precaution, add `.` to your PATH:

```
$env:PATH =$env:PATH+";."
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this trick stopped working with the latest versions (tested with PowerShell 7.1.3). The generic error message is followed by this: `Suggestion [3,General]: The command mycommand was not found, but does exist in the current location. PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\mycommand". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.`

Comment: @IgorAkkerman, It works for me in Powershell 7.2.0.  Want to try again--maybe it was a regression since fixed?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Thanks for the clue, it works for me in 7.2.1 as well.

Comment: This no longer works for me in 7.2.4.  Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Is there a way to subvert the precaution permanently?

Answer (score 3):

add in your `path` (evironment variable) the path where you usually put your `script` and `exe` file.

Comment: This is my environment variable:
ANDROID_HOME:
C:\Users\berke\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

In platform-tools there is adb.exe i cant run adb exe globally what should i do...?

Answer (score -2):

Rename your script file so that it starts with a '.'.

See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9468