# Python not running in powershell

Tags: python, powershell

I am trying to follow learn python the hard way but it won't load in the powershell. I typed in the exact line that is

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27", "User")
```

but I know that won't work cause that isn't where python is installed. I am on a school computer so I have my python installed in mi_lemi(\filer_useres)(G:) but I tried putting that in instead and fiddling around with it but no luck either. Also my python.exe is just alled python.exe so should I remeove the '27' from it?

Thanks!

Comment: The python.exe executable is in a dir called C:\Python27, right?

Comment: No its not its installed in the directory I posted above. The default directory for the powershell is also different. I copied all the python files in to the default directory and it seems to work now but I am having trouble loading files... I will try to figure it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running Python in powershell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676403/running-python-in-powershell)

Answer (score 1):

That call will work for subsequent invocations of PowerShell but it won't help the current PowerShell session.  For the current session use:

```
$env:Path += ";C:\Python27"
python.exe
```

or

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27", "Process")
python.exe
```

Or perhaps just:

```
C:\> c:\python27\python.exe
```

Comment: Thank you. I used your 2nd comment and it said "the command python.exe was not found but does exist in your current location..... if you trust this command instead type .\python.exe" So I did that but it said it was missing some files. I copied them all over from the directory I listed in my first post to the directory that the powershell starts in and it seems to work for now.....

Comment: If you are cd'd into the same directory as the executable then you have to execute the exe like so `.\python.exe`.  That is a security feature of PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this is also the issue.  I found Python replaced my PathExt content as well.  Check your  PathExt environment variable as well just in case it's been replaced with .PY.

It should look something like this.

```
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I finally found how to fix it.

First search python in the windows search, Python 3.7 (32-bit)  or another version of python should show up. (If not first install Python.)

Then Right click on it and choose   open location   then you should see a folder with Python in it.

If the python in that folder is a shortcut, right click on it and choose open location again. (This step is only required if it is a shortcut.)

When you have found the real Python.exe, click on the path wich is above the files on the file manager, copy it.

Then go to Windows PowerShell and type:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;INSERT WHAT YOU COPIED HERE")
```

In my case:

```
C:\Users\Stijn> [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Users\INSERT WINDOWS USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32")
```

That fixed it for me.