# I need to get a .py file to open in command prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to programming, my only experience is a semester of high school computer science. I am using Canopy, and I am running windows 10. I currently have a program that when run in Canopy, gives me my total ram, cpu usage, ram usage, ETC. I want to make it so that I can run this program on most computers running windows, preferably opening in command prompt. What is the easiest or most stable way of doing this? 
I can provide the code if it would help in answering the question.
Thank you for your time, 
V.Montori

EDIT 
I may have explained that poorly. My program is currently to print out my cpu usage, ram stats, etc. in the Canopy output thing. I want to make it so that I can double click my program on any windows computer and have it print out the same stats but in a command prompt window or something similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Python in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676403/running-python-in-powershell)

Comment: Is this what you are seeking? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency

Comment: Believe it was answered here before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621255/how-do-i-run-a-python-program-in-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7

Comment: What do you mean by "opening in command prompt"?  Do you mean that you want to launch it from the Windows command shell?  You want it to launch to its own command line?  You want to use Python interactive (command) mode?