# Looking for a way where I can invoke a Chrome Browser on Remote windows server

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, windows-server

There are no resources available on the windows server apart from powershell and was looking for a way if it is possible to RDP to the windows server using Python and Selenium from the local machine and then perform some actions on the Chrome browser in the Remote Windows Server

Comment: You can try running a python script on the server, by taking RDP of the server using Powershell and then triggering the python script using a `.bat` file through Powershell RDP.
And whatever operations you want to do with the chrome browser, you can write it all in the python script.
OR
You can trigger the python script without the need of a `.bat` file following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676403/running-python-in-powershell)

Comment: Thanks Shreyas my problem is I don't have python on the Server, the only option I have on the server is powershell. So just wanted to understand if the python- selenium script can run on my local machine RDP to the remote server and invoke the Chrome browser to perform actions, or can I use python from my local machine to just RDP on the remote server and then somehow make use of powershell on the server

Comment: Nope, you cannot use the python of your host machine to run the script on the server which you would access through RDP. The server will require python to be able to run Python scripts. However, I came across something that I haven't tried myself. Maybe you can have a look [here](http://www.py2exe.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the direction Shreyas will try that