# Pandas crash while importing in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pip, crash

[screenshot traceback of importing pandas in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOfRu.png) [Screenshot of pop up when trying to execute script using terminal, "Python has stopped working"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngFVU.png) [ScreenShot of pop up window saying Python has stopped working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9YIW.png) While import pandas or numpy, python crash and displays "python has stopped working", currently running python 3.11.3 version of pandas is 2.0.1 and numpy is 1.24.3 and windows version is 8.1 32 bit

reinstalling pandas multiple times, upgraded pip to latest version, reinstalled python restarted pc, path is currently set, can import any other libraries it works perfectly fine but cannot import two library pandas and numpy

Comment: Is this the only traceback? I will be difficult to reproduce/investigate with so little.

Comment: I tried to upgrade pandas but it says it's already satisfied and the pop up window doesn't show any information is there a way to find traceback of that?

Comment: What I mean is, during the crash, is "python has stopped working" the full error message?

Comment: i have attached image, after it tries to solve problem it says "a problem caused the program to stop working corrrectly. Windows will close the program and notify you is a solution is available"

Comment: Difficult to debug with only that… sorry… I hope you'll find the issue

Comment: Get rid of "click to invoke" and invoke your script from terminal ("cmd" or "powershell", not sure regarding exact steps for windows, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676403/running-python-in-powershell)) to get some debugging info. Update the question with the traceback you receive.

Comment: Also post your basic hardware info - pandas and numpy are much closer to native hardware than usual python packages, and this may be important (ideally like linux `lscpu` output for CPU, search for how to obtain something similar on windows).

Comment: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOfRu.png] I added traceback image which i could find @SUTerliakov

Comment: That's much better, now please post it as text - the image is unreadable.